# How can I create a shared_ptr to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to create a shared_ptr to a std::vector, what is the correct syntax?

```
std::vector<uint8_t> mVector;
shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> mSharedPtr = &mVector;
```

The code above does not compile.

Thanks.

Comment: `auto p = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t>>();`

Answer (score 36):

What you are trying to do is to let a smart pointer manage a stack object. This doesn't work, as the stack object is going to kill itself when it goes out of scope. The smart pointer can't prevent it from doing this.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t> > sp;
{
   std::vector<uint8_t> mVector;
   sp=std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t> >(&mVector);
}
sp->empty();   // dangling reference, as mVector is already destroyed
```

---

**Three alternatives:**

(1) Initialize the vector and let it manage by the `shared_ptr`:

```
auto mSharedPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t> >(/* vector constructor arguments*/);
```

(2) Manage a copy of the vector (by invoking the vector copy constructor):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> mVector;
auto mSharedPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t> >(mVector);
```

(3) Move the vector (by invoking the vector move constructor):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> mVector;
auto mSharedPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t> >(std::move(mVector));
//don't use mVector anymore.
```

---

Answer (score 7):

First, what you're doing is very wrong, if you give a pointer to a shared_ptr make sure it's dynamically allocated with `new`, not on the stack. Otherwise you may just as well use a pointer instead of a shared_ptr.

Your code should be:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> mVector;
/* Copy the vector in a shared pointer */
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t> > mSharedPtr ( new std::vector<uint8_t>(mVector) );
```

or:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t> > mSharedPtr ( new std::vector<uint8_t>() );
```

As for why it doesn't compile, you need to use the constructor, not the `=` operator.

As pointed out by @remyabel, [make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) is more efficient:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> vector;
/* Copy the vector in a shared pointer */
auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t>> (vector);
```

Comment: Why not `std::make_shared`?

Comment: Yes make_shared is more efficient.

Comment: Its also provides a bit more protection against memory leaks during exceptions.

Comment: Note that your version of `make_shared` always call the vector copy constructor. You could also forward the vector's constructor arguments.

Comment: That one is intended, as I'm making a copy, following what I understand of the intent of the OP. The variables start by m, which makes it likely that they are member variables, and so i'm not using `std::move` .

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't compile because you are assigning a raw pointer '`&mVector`' to smart pointer '`mSharedPtr`' which are two different objects and no casting is allowed.

you can do that by other approaches

(1) intializing your `shared_ptr` with the raw pointer from the begining

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> sPtr (&mVector);
```

(2) using `reset()` method of `shared_ptr`

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> sPtr;
sPtr.reset(&mVector);
```

assigning a stack object raw pointer to smart pointer , you should also supply an empty deleter to the smart pointer, so that the smart pointer doesn't delete the object when it is still on the stack.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> sPtr (&mVector,[](std::vector<uint8_t>*){});
```